# How to remove flooding from text via js?

Tags: javascript, text, replace

I don't know the name of what I want, so I'll show you.

I have an input text where users can ask questions, but there are some users asking questions like these:
`What the?????????????????????%%%%%%` or `Question??????????????????????` .... 
or `!!!!!!??????` .... etc.

I would like to remove these strings from my javascript variable. Which function will help me? And what is the english name for what I'm looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: From a usability point of view, you shouldn't. StackOverflow doesn't even prevent you from doing so. Also, what's the criteria for "flooding"? If I entered a random, non-pattern mix of characters, is it still flooding? How would you know? If I entered `??!@!@@@@#!$%%!@%%#%#%#$#@#$!@##`, does it count?

Comment: What would classify something as "flooding"? How many consecutive occurrences?

Comment: That's flooding when the question is only `????????????????` . This is not a real question. Our pages are not for programmers, that's for simple questions, but if users see a lots of spam question, they wont use it. I think in a question you don't use this `??`, you use this `?` .. Only one question mark or `What is this? How?` This is good too...

Comment: @user2301881 [StackOverflow isn't the only site in StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites), and half of them aren't even for programmers.

Comment: I see. But my users can ask only real questions, that containing correct hungarian grammar. They accept it, but they don't do it.

Comment: Use a regexp to compress sequences of special characters to one character. But it won't stop questions such as "i have a question?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example in JavaScript, but the regexp will be very similar in other languages:

```
var compressSpecialChars = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\w\d\s]+/g, function(specials) { return specials[0] });
};

var questions = [
    'What the?????????????????????%%%%%%',
    'Question??????????????????????',
    '!!!!!!??????'
];

questions.map(compressSpecialChars);
// Result: ["What the?", "Question?", "!"]
```

Comment: Do you know what about: `I'm hungry, but what should I eat?` ... ` and , are special chars too.. :-(

Comment: Oops, I haven't thought about ", ". I've updated the answer, it should work better now. As for ellipsis, it would require 2-step filtering. First filter all other special chars, and then filter "." with another regexp: `str.replace(/[.]{3,}/g, '...')`